Reverse all text files in all path with output separate independently
My code run successfully but I want that output files will be separate independently.
import os

path = '/txt_files_path/' # txt files path

for filename in filter(lambda p: p.endswith("txt"), os.listdir(path)):
    filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
    with open(filepath, mode='r') as f:
      for line in f:
        addr = line.rstrip()

    var = line.rstrip()
    data = var
    data_1 = data[::-1]

    os.system(f'echo {(var[::-1])} >> output.txt') # single txt reverse files output write

The problem is the last line.
I want that output files will be separate independently.

output files will be separate independently which means?

You never do anything with addr or data_1. What are these variables for?

Why are you using os.system() to write to the output file? Why not just open the file in python and write to it?

did you ask chatgpt to write this code? because the answer to your question is already in it

import os

path = 'test_folder/' # txt files path

for filename in filter(lambda p: p.endswith("txt"), os.listdir(path)):
    filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
    with open(filepath, mode='r') as f:
      for line in f:
        addr = line.rstrip()

    var = line.rstrip()
    data = var
    data_1 = data[::-1]

    os.system(f'echo {(var[::-1])} >> {filename}_reversed.txt') # single txt reverse files output write

Your code repeatedly writes (and hence overwrites) to the same file. All you need to do is everytime it writes, make sure you are writing to a unique file.
